# Subdomains and Folders

Tags: html, subdomain, directory, image

Just started a site and I have an `/img` directory on the main domain.  I would like to set up a subdomain(where the file folder is just another one in the main directory) that is able to use the `/img` folder but it doesn't work.

The /img and /subdomain folders are on the same level, so to display images in the main domain I type: `<img src="img/image.jpg">`
and for the /subdomain I type: `<img src="../img/image.jpg">`
and I get a 404 error for the site: *http://subdomain.example.com/img/image.jpg*
As you can see, I want it to be linking to *http://www.example.com/img/image.jpg*

**Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?** I would prefer not to link images to their internet directory (i.e. *http://www...*) because I would like to modify the sites on my computer and upload them via ftp.

I'm sure it's just something that I am messing up or don't completely understand.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What web server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative paths are always relative to a [URI](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt). If you have a page at http://subdomain.example.com/ containing a link to ../img/image.jpg, the web server translates it into a link to http://subdomain.example.com/../img/image.jpg. Obviously the web server can't serve anything above it's root directory (that's the whole point of having a root).

Your webserver is configured to only serve content in the /subdomain directory, but obviously /img is not inside that directory, and can't thus be served. What you need to do is configure your webserver to look in /img (the directory on your filesystem) instead of /subdomain/img when it gets an request for any content at http://subdomain.example.com/img/

With Apache this can be done with [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html).

Summary: Use mod_alias to map requests to http://subdomain.example.com/img/ to the directory /img.