# Subdomains and Folders

Tags: html, subdomain, directory, image, bluehost

Just started a site and I have an `/img` directory on the main domain. I would like to set up a subdomain(where the file folder is just another one in the main directory) that is able to use the `/img` folder, but it doesn't work.

The `/img` and `/subdomain` folders are on the same level, so to display images in the main domain I type: `<img src="img/image.jpg">` 
and for the `/subdomain` I type: `<img src="../img/image.jpg">` 
and I get a 404 error for the site: *http://subdomain.example.com/img/image.jpg* As you can see, I want it to be linking to *http://www.example.com/img/image.jpg*

**Can anyone tell me how to achieve this?** I would prefer not to link images to their internet directory (i.e. *http://www...*) because I would like to modify the sites on my computer and upload them via ftp to my site hosted by bluehost.com.

I'm sure it's just something that I am messing up or don't completely understand. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451463

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your folder structure on your web server, create a symbolic link `/subdomain/img` pointing to the target `/img`.

In linux, this can be done by:

```
cd /your_web_folder/subdomain
ln /your_web_folder/img img -s
```

Comment: ServAce85: It cannot. You will have to modify something on your server.

Comment: gotcha.  yeah, that's what i figured about 3 seconds after i pressed "add comment"

thanks Fragsworth for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use subdomains for asset management.  From an enterprise perspective you will end up with hundreds of subdomains and have no idea what each represents.  I know this must sound absurd, but I have seen it happen.

I would strongly recommend using a well thought out directory structure that balances asset types against versioning information.  I would also recommend using a content distribution system, such as the edgesuite networks.

Comment: could you be a little more specific as to what you're talking about, please.  I'm somewhat new to hosting sites and don't completely get what you're talking about.  thx.

Comment: I am just saying that using subdomains as a means of managing site assets is a bad idea that typically becomes a slippy slope of management failure.  Let me know what questions you have specifically.